Definability in a lexicographic order structure
I have a question about a definability of a particular singleton in a given structure.
Structure is $(\{0\} \times \mathbb{Q} \cup \{1\} \times \{0\} \cup \{ 2 \} \times \mathbb{Q}, \leq _{lex}) $,
and the set to define (or to prove it's undefinable) is $ \{ <1, 0>\} $.
I don't see neither how I could show its definability nor undefinability.

I believe the set you are looking at is not definable. To see why we will build an automorphism of the structure which does not fix the point $\langle0,1\rangle$. Pick your favorite point $p$ in the first copy of the rationals and map it to $\langle0,1\rangle$ while mapping $\langle0,1\rangle$ to your favorite point $q$ in the second copy of the rationals. The interval of elements less than $p$ in your ordering can be put in order-preserving bijection with the first copy of the rationals, the interval between $p$ and $\langle0,1\rangle$ can be put in order-preserving bijection with the interval between $\langle0,1\rangle$ and $q$, and the second copy of the rationals can be placed in order-preserving bijection with the interval of elements greater than $q$. It helps to draw a picture. Does this make any sense?

And it doesn't matter what's the exact value of q in second copy cause of density, yes? I want to make sure if I get it right

Essentially, yes. There is no least element of the rationals and for any rational $q$ there is no greatest rational less than $q$. So, for instance, the interval of rationals less than $q$ is a countable, dense linear order without endpoints, just like the rationals themselves. I think that answers your question, but let me know if otherwise.

Yes, it does! Many thanks:)

@Rikimaru Please note that your structure is actually isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Q},\leq)$, since it is a countable dense linear order without endpoints. So the phrasing of the question is a bit of a red herring: it is equivalent to ask whether ${0}$ is definable in $(\mathbb{Q},\leq)$.
